# How to find document in mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

**How i can find certain userId in mongoose?**
I have this code:

```
{
   _id: String,
   tagName: 'git',
   users: [
       {userId: 1, count: 1}
       {userId: 234232342, count: 1}
   ]
}
```

**I tried to find with**

```
const checkUser = await Tag.findOne({
        tagName: params.tag],
        users: { $in: { userId: params.userId } },
      });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `params.userId` holds a single value, you can simply do:

```
const checkUser = await Tag.findOne({
   "users.userId": params.userId
});
```

I've omitted `tagName` as you did not include it in your schema ..

Comment: Thks,  and how i can update certain count by using userId?

Comment: Please check for existing posts on stackoverflow, this has been answered many times. If you still need help, ask a new question instead of editing the existing one :)